# Is the order of iterating through std::map known (and guaranteed by the standard)?

Tags: c++, stl, iteration, language-lawyer, stdmap

What I mean is - we know that the `std::map`'s elements are sorted according to the keys. So, let's say the keys are integers. If I iterate from `std::map::begin()` to `std::map::end()` using a `for`, does the standard guarantee that I'll iterate consequently through the elements with keys, sorted in ascending order?

---

Example:

```
std::map<int, int> map_;
map_[1] = 2;
map_[2] = 3;
map_[3] = 4;
for( std::map<int, int>::iterator iter = map_.begin();
     iter != map_.end();
     ++iter )
{
    std::cout << iter->second;
}
```

Is this guaranteed to print `234` or is it implementation defined?

---

Real life reason: I have a `std::map` with `int` keys. In very rare situations, I'd like to iterate through all elements, with key, greater than a concrete `int` value. Yep, it sounds like `std::vector` would be the better choice, but notice my "very rare situations".

---

**EDIT**: I know, that the elements of `std::map` are sorted.. no need to point it out (for most of the answers here). I even wrote it in my question.
I was asking about the iterators and the order when I'm iterating through a container. Thanks @Kerrek SB for the answer.

Comment: In case you didn't know: in your real life use you can use `map::upper_bound` to find the point to start iterating.

Comment: I know this and I know the exact place I'd start iterating. I just wandered if the order is guaranteed.

Comment: A sparse vector wouldn't be sensible if your keys (numeric indices) vary tremendously across the board.  I'm using a similar solution for which the numeric index represents a Cartesian y-coordinate in 3-dimensional space.  Using a vector in this scenario would increase my memory footprint by gigabytes.  So I don't think the vector is a panacea here, far from it.

Comment: I don't understand the question, and I'll explain why through a thought-experiment. If you already know that the elements are ordered, how could iteration not be? What does ordering even mean, if it doesn't apply to iteration? What other cases are there where order matters, is detectable, etc.? (The answer was given by [Konstantin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7649415/2757035).)

Comment: This is actually quite a funny phenomenon :)  People who understand data structure would *not* understand this question, but people who visualize std::map like a "list" would understand why this question was asked. (of course std::map is not a list). Actually, @underscore_d's comment hit home :)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Yes, that's guaranteed. Moreover, `*begin()` gives you the smallest and `*rbegin()` the largest element, as determined by the comparison operator, and two key values `a` and `b` for which the expression `!compare(a,b) && !compare(b,a)` is true are considered equal. The default comparison function is `std::less<K>`.

The ordering is not a lucky bonus feature, but rather, it is a fundamental aspect of the data structure, as the ordering is used to determine when two keys are the same (by the above rule) and to perform efficient lookup (essentially a binary search, which has logarithmic complexity in the number of elements).

Comment: std::map is implemented using binary trees, so technically no binary search is performed.

Comment: @jupp0r: Structuring a range as a binary search tree is a particular method to implement binary search through the range. "Binary search" is an abstract concept rather than a particular implementation. It doesn't matter whether you jump through offsets into an array or follow link nodes; those are just specific ways of "bisecting the range".

Comment: I know this is an old post, but to be clear the "efficient lookup" is relative. Technically the `std::unordered_map` has a more efficient lookup time of O(1). The advantage of `std::map` is in key ordering, but not lookup.

Comment: @AdamJohnston: in general case with an appropiate key bit distribution you are right. But remember that O(1) is not guaranteed, in worse case scenario it degenerates to O(n). In contrast, O(log n) is guaranteed for any kind of key in the case of std::map.

Answer (score 48):

This is guaranteed by Associative container requirements in the C++ standard. E.g. see 23.2.4/10 in C++11:

```
The fundamental property of iterators of associative containers is that they
iterate through the containers in the non-descending order of keys where
non-descending is defined by the comparison that was used to construct them.
For any two dereferenceable iterators i and j such that distance from i to j is
positive,
  value_comp(*j, *i) == false
```

and 23.2.4/11

```
For associative containers with unique keys the stronger condition holds,
  value_comp(*i, *j) != false.
```

Answer (score 47):

I think there is a confusion in data structures.

In most languages, a `map` is simply an AssociativeContainer: it maps a key to a value. In the "newer" languages, this is generally achieved using a hash map, thus no order is guaranted.

In C++, however, this is not so:

- `std::map` is a **sorted** associative container
- `std::unordered_map` is a hash-table based associative container introduced in C++11

So, in order to clarify the guarantees on ordering.

**In C++03:**

- `std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::map` and `std::multimap` are guaranteed to be ordered according to the keys (and the criterion supplied)
- in `std::multiset` and `std::multimap`, the standard does not impose any order guarantee on equivalent elements (ie, those which compare equal)

**In C++11:**

- `std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::map` and `std::multimap` are guaranteed to be ordered according to the keys (and the criterion supplied)
- in `std::multiset` and `std::multimap`, the Standard *imposes* that equivalent elements (those which compare equal) are ordered according to their insertion order (first inserted first)
- `std::unordered_*` containers are, as the name imply, not ordered. Most notably, the order of elements *may* change when the container is modified (upon insertion/deletion).

When the Standard says that elements are ordered in a way, it means that:

- when iterating, you see the elements in the order defined
- when iterating in reverse, you see the elements in the opposite order

I hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with my question, sorry :) I know which one are ordered, and which - not. And I'm asking for the order when I'm iterating through the elements.

Comment: @KirilKirov: well, the *definition* of an ordered associative container is that when iterating through it the elements are ordered.

Comment: Well, I guess you're right, but I didn't know that and that's exactly what I was asking :)

Answer (score 7):

> Is this guaranteed to print 234 or it's implementation defined?

Yes, `std::map` is a sorted container, ordered by the `Key` with the supplied `Comparator`. So it is guaranteed.

> I'd like go iterate through all elements, with key, greater than a concrete int value.

That is surely possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes ... the elements in a `std::map` have a strict weak-ordering, meaning that the elements will be composed of a set (i.e., there will be no repeats of keys that are "equal"), and equality is determined by testing on any two keys A and B, that if key A is not less than key B, and B is not less than A, then key A is equal to key B.

That being said, you cannot properly sort the elements of a `std::map` if the weak-ordering for that type is ambiguous (in your case, where you are using integers as the key-type, that is not a problem).  You must be able to define a operation that defines a total order on the type you are using for the keys in your `std::map`, otherwise you will only have a partial order for your elements, or poset, which has property where A may not be comparable to B.  What will typically happen in this scenario is that you'll be able to insert the key/value pairs, but you may end up with duplicate key/value pairs if you iterate through the entire map, and/or detect "missing" key/value pairs when you attempt to perform a `std::map::find()` of a specific key/value pair in the map.

Comment: As the other answers, this does not actually answers my question, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake I'd like to mention that if your container includes *pointers*, the iteration order may differ in each new program run due to [ASLR](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/definition/address-space-layout-randomization-ASLR#:%7E:text=Address%20space%20layout%20randomization%20(ASLR)%20is%20a%20memory%2Dprotection,executables%20are%20loaded%20into%20memory.&text=ASLR%20is%20able%20to%20put%20address%20space%20targets%20in%20unpredictable%20locations.). So even though the order in one run *is* deterministic, the order across multiple runs is *not*.

Whether this is important for correctness depends on particular program.

Answer (score -6):

begin() may give the smallest element. But it is implementation depended. Is it specified in the C++ standard? If not, then it is dangerous to make this assumption.