# Are c++ std::map<string,string> ordered?

Tags: c++

are STL maps ordered?

Specifically I need to know if std::map is ordered. So if I iterate over it, it will iterate with the first insert string first.

So will the below iterate A, C then B consistantly?

```
std::map<string,string> str_map;

str_map.insert(std::make_pair("A","Data"));
str_map.insert(std::make_pair("C","Data"));
str_map.insert(std::make_pair("B","Data"));
```

Comment: Yes, you can actually pass in your own compare function so you can have it ordered however you want.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/

Comment: CodingQuant: Actually your example is not very good, since it doesn't distinguish between two meanings of "ordered": insertion order, and lexicographical order.  std::map preserves *lexicographical* order, not insertion order.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: To be pedantic, std::map preserves lexicographical order only if your comparison predicate is based on a lexicographical comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A std::map that keep track of the order of insertion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648756/is-the-order-of-iterating-through-stdmap-known-and-guaranteed-by-the-standard

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> are STL maps ordered?

Yes, a `std::map<K,V>` is ordered based on the key, `K`, using [`std::less<K>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) to compare objects, by default.

> So if I iterate over it, it will iterate with the first insert string first?

No.  It will iterate based on the sorted order, not the order that you inserted elements.  In the case of `std::string`, it sorts in lexicographic order (alphabetic order).

If you want to iterate based on the insertion order, you're better off using a sequence container, such as a `std::vector` or a `std::list`.

Comment: Thanks - but it the sorting alphabetic? I've updated the question to put C before B. Thanks a lot

Comment: @CodingQuant: Answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

`std::map`s are sorted using either the given type's `operator<` or using a custom comparison function/functor if one is supplied as an argument to the constructor.

So no, when you iterate over the map, the first item you get won't be the one you inserted first - it will be the one that comes first alphabetically.

Of course for your sample code that doesn't make a difference because "A" is the first key you inserted and also the first one alphabetically.

Comment: By default std::map uses `std::less<Key>`. How this works depends on the type Key but for normal STL types it is usually `operator<`