# hybrid linked list constructed on unordered_map?

Tags: c++, linked-list, unordered-map

Hi I wonder if I can set up another linked struct myself to actually set up my own order between keys in the unordered_map? or there is a standard library? I need the fast look up function of unordered_map...

For example:

```
#include<string>
#include<tr1/unordered_map>

struct linker
{
    string *pt;
    string *child1;
    string *child2;
};

unordered_map<string,int> map({{"aaa",1},{"bbb",2},{"ccc",3},{"ddd",4}});

linker node1 = new linker;
node1.pt = &map.find("aaa")->first;
node1.child1 = &map.find("ccc")->first;
node1.child2 = &map.find("ddd")->first;
```

Comment: It might be better to store iterators instead of pointers.

Comment: @Nick but the iterators will change if the size changes and rehashed. isn't it?

Comment: There are many things that invalidate the iterators and the pointers, you have to be careful either way.

Comment: @Nick So create another struct to store the key value would be much safer and easier to use?

Comment: What about a shared_ptr?

Answer (score 0):

One way to optimize hash lookup is to find a hash function that produces the smallest number of hash collisions on the keys you are going to use.

With `std::unordered_map` you can also [get local iterators to buckets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/begin2) and rearrange the elements in the bucket, if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

A far better solution IMHO would be as follows:

```
struct comparator {
    bool operator()(string const& lhs, string const& rhs) {
        return ...;//Your definition of order here!!!
        }
};

std::map<string, int, comparator> map{{"aaa",1},{"bbb",2},{"ccc",3},{"ddd",4}};//note the elided paranthesis
```

Now you can simply use the iterator pair begin()/end() of this map which will be in a specified order see in the accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648756/is-the-order-of-iterating-through-stdmap-known-and-guaranteed-by-the-standard)