# How to find min/max in std::map like in std::set?

Tags: c++, c++11, set, stdmap, stdset

Since both set and map are ordered containers, can the min and the max be found in 0(1) time for std::map like in std::set ?

```
// for std::set
// std::set<int> s;
auto min = *s.begin();

auto max = *s.rbegin();
```

How do I obtain the max and min in O(1) from a std::map ? Other questions here seem to suggest to iterate through the map, but can't we use the ordered properlt of std::map to obtain the result faster ?

Comment: No I don;t believe that is possble. since the sorting on a map depends on the key type.

Comment: So can I find the smallest key in 0(1) time ?

Comment: I had a [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7648812) a while ago.

Comment: @KerrekSB Didn't see it earlier. Thanks, it has more details too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dereference first from the iterator for the key, like this:

```
// for std::map<int,string> s
auto minKey = s.begin()->first;
auto maxKey = s.rbegin()->first;
```

This works only for keys, not values, because maps are sorted only on their keys.

Comment: beautiful thank you. It seemed to me that there has to be a better way than iterating through it. I though this might be the answer, but wanted to check.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to find the smallest key.

Comment: This answer is very clever, but I found the wording of "Dereference first from the iterator for the key, like this" took me a few parses to grok. Might be worth adding an extra sentence saying that maps are always stored in order so the key of the first/last elements will be smallest/largest respectively. Regardless +1.